# React + SocketIO

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I'm trying to develop a real-time quiz game using React and Socket IO. What I'm trying to achieve is when a player connects to a lobby other players should know it. Following is the code:

React

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Modal, Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
const socketIOClient = require("socket.io-client");

class PlayArea extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      playerList: [],
    };
    this.socket = socketIOClient('ip address');
    this.socket.on('onPlayerJoin', data => {
      this.setState({ playerList: data.playerList });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      Players Joined : <ul>{
              this.state.playerList.map(player =>
                (<li key={player.playerId}>{player.playerId}</li>)
              )
            }</ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Backend server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

let playerId = 0;
let playerList = [];
let playerData = {
  playerId: null,
}

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

  console.log('A player has joined');

  playerData.playerId = playerId;
  playerId = playerId + 1;

  playerList.push({ playerId: playerId });

  socket.emit('onPlayerJoin', { playerList: playerList });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });

});

http.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3001');
});
```

The problem is when I open the page in a new browser instance(simulating a new player joining), the first instance is not receiving the "onPlayerJoin" event.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
 socket.emit('onPlayerJoin', { playerList: playerList });
```

with

```
socket.broadcast.emit('onPlayerJoin', { playerList: playerList });
```

This will send to all connected sockets except the sender while socket.emit only sends to that particular socket that got connected.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the backend. Using `socket.emit()`,
you are sending the event only to the client that just connected.
You can use:

`socket.broadcast.emit()` - send the event to all connected clients **except the sender**

`io.emit()` - send the event to all connected clients.

Here is a cheatsheet: https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have used ```io.emit()``` and it works as required.